# How to pass data from javascript file to a view without using querystrings

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

On the click event of a button and after doing some logic,
I want to pass a variable called sqpage to another page and use
the variable name to make some decisions.
At the moment I am using a query string and it works. I dont
want this to show in the url as it shows now

Please note that my code below exist in a .js file(javascript file)

How can I pass a variable from jquery code in a js file to a view

```
            $('#Continue').click(function() {

                .... some logic here

                if (countOfNo > 0) {
                    window.location = "../Home/SayThanks2";
                } else {
                    window.location.href = "../Home/Register?pageType=" + "sqpage";

                }
            });

             public ActionResult Register(string pageType)
             {
                return View(Register);
             }
```

Comment: Use a form that `POST` 's the data instead.

Answer (score 0):

Post data.

You will want to take a look at [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: While using POST to do this is correct, the rest of your answer is just flat out wrong. If you're using AJAX, you don't need a physical HTML form or even hidden inputs; you can pass any arbitrary bit of data you like as the post body directly in the AJAX call.

Comment: @ChrisPratt ...oh geeze, I must be too early in the morning.  I completely blanked on jquery's `.ajax()` oi.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use this in place of that line of code.

```
//window.location.href = "../Home/Register?pageType=" + "sqpage";
$.post('Home/Register', { pageType: 'sqpage' });
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks simple and works. How can I add another parameter to this?

Comment: the second argument is JSON, so you can add as many params you want. Like { 'param1_Name':'param1_value','param2_name':'param2_value' } and so on.